# Using PowerShell to extract text from an xml's meta tag

Tags: xml, powershell, epub

With the following xml file, how can I extract some of the meta tag's text?  For example, I want to get the text "aut" out of the meta tag with the property "role" attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0" xml:lang="en" unique-identifier="pub-  id" prefix="cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns#">
    <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <dc:title id="title">Moby-Dick</dc:title>
        <meta refines="#title" property="title-type">main</meta>
        <dc:creator id="creator">Herman Melville</dc:creator>
        <meta refines="#creator" property="file-as">MELVILLE, HERMAN</meta>
        <meta refines="#creator" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>
        <dc:identifier id="pub-id">code.google.com.epub-samples.moby-dick-basic</dc:identifier>
        <dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
        <meta property="dcterms:modified">2012-01-18T12:47:00Z</meta>
        <dc:publisher>Harper &amp; Brothers, Publishers</dc:publisher>
        <dc:contributor id="contrib1">Dave Cramer</dc:contributor>
        <meta refines="#contrib1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">mrk</meta>
        <dc:rights>This work is shared with the public using the Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) license.</dc:rights>        
        <link rel="cc:license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"/>
        <meta property="cc:attributionURL">http://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/</meta>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

I've tried using the selectsinglenode() method as such with no success:

```
[xml]$doc = get-content myxmlfile.xml
$node = $doc.selectsinglenode("/package/metadata/meta[@property='role']")

//and

$node = $doc.selectsinglenode("//meta[@property='role']")

// $node is null for both cases
```

I've also tried using Select-XML as such:

```
[xml]$doc = get-content myxmlfile.xml
Select-Xml -xml $doc -Xpath "/package/metadata/meta[@property='role']"

//and

Select-Xml -xml $doc -Xpath "//meta[@property='role']"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  tag defined a default namespace. You either need to define that default namespace or use a wildcard to avoid specifying a namespace. The latter is easier:

```
select-xml -xml $xml -xpath "//*[@property='role']/text()" | % { $_.Node.Value }
```

Here are a couple of references: 
http://blog.stevex.net/xpath-and-xml-namespaces/
http://huddledmasses.org/xpath-and-namespaces-in-powershell/

Comment: thank you, that was the information I was lacking being new to xml parsing.  I'll research more on namespaces, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to find the role nodes :

```
$xmlFile = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\meta.xml)
$xmlFile.package.metadata.meta |Where-Object {$_.property -eq "role"}
$xmlFile.package.metadata.meta |Where-Object {$_.property -eq "role"} | foreach {$_.innertext}
```

Comment: thank you, this does work, but I'd like to ask you the same question as I did for EBGreen.  How come my two methods don't work?  It seemed to work in another example when there are no "meta" tags.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods here is one:

```
[xml]$foo = Get-Content PATH\TO\FILE.xml
$foo.package.metadata.meta | ?{$_.property -eq 'role'} | Select '#text'

#text
-----
aut
mrk
```

That would get both the role nodes. To get just the one with aut:

```
$foo.package.metadata.meta | ?{($_.property -eq 'role') -and ($_.refines -eq '#creator')} | Select '#text'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, however is there a reason why the methods I've tried don't work?  It seemed to work in other examples where the tag isn't "meta".  Is there something about the "meta" tag that powershell doesn't like?

Comment: @subject_x The reason your approaches don't work is that if you use XPath, you need to reference the correct namespaces. Powershell's "native" XML functionality hides this, so when you say `$foo.package.metadata.meta` it doesn't matter that `package` and `metadata` are in different namespaces. With XPath, it does.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the text contained in each of the "meta"nodes:

```
PS> $xml = [xml](gc .\pkg.xml)
PS> $xml.package.metadata.meta | % {write-output $_."#text"}
```

Output:

```
main
MELVILLE, HERMAN
aut
2012-01-18T12:47:00Z
mrk
http://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/
```